# Intellij doesn't recognise the Ruby interpreter properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, intellij-idea

I've been struggling with setting the proper version of Ruby interpreter onto Intellij.

Error says :: `Safe navigation operator requires at least Ruby 2.3`

I understand what the error means here. It means "This feature is not available in your current Ruby version."

However I don't know how I can fix this in Intellij Build: 163.10154.41, event I set up correctly Ruby SDK.

**The Ruby version used in this project is 2.3.1 with rbenv.**

How could I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Removing `{document_root}/.idea` directory and import the project to IntelliJ again and then, it worked back when I met the same kind of issue before.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is to remove the autodetected module from the project and then add a new Ruby module to the project (choose *New Module*, not *Import Module*).

Wiping out `.idea` and/or reimporting doesn't work (for me) because IntelliJ always imports the project/module incorrectly. Specifically, IntelliJ doesn't seem to recognize it as a Ruby module, and hence the project's Ruby SDK settings have no effect.

Comment: There seems to be no pure-ruby module though, only Ruby on Rails :(